# Why Do I Get Different Results Between "For" and "While"?

Tags: c++, vector

So, I'm working on a project which detects the coordinates of dots.

I extract the detected coordinate from `std::vector<cv::Point> dots` and store each of the x and y coordinate to `std::vector<int> dotsX` and `std::vector<int> dotsY`. (I know that I can use `dots.x` or `dots.y` instead, but that's not what I want)

Whenever I want to print the output, I get different results between a `for` loop and a `while` loop to show the value vectors. For an example:

The detected X coordinate are 15,20,50 and the detected Y coordinate are 2, 10, 20.

If I use the `for` loop:

```
for(int x=0;x < dotsX.size();x++)
{
     std::cout << dotsX[x] << std::endl;
}
```

The outputs are the same: 15,20,50.

But, if I use the `while` loop:

```
int x=0;
while(dotsX[x])
{
    std::cout << dotsX[x] << std::endl;
    x++;
}
```

The output are weird: 15, 20, 50, 32. There is always a additional value in it (like the value 32, sometimes 10201 or 4, etc).

I don't know why is that happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Your `while` loop is checking **values**.  The `for` loop is checking **quantities**.  Two distinct separate concepts.

Answer (score 6):

The second example has undefined behavior, since it always end up accesing an out-of-bounds element of `dotsX`.

To make it identical to the `for` loop, change it into:

```
while(x < dots.size())
{
    // ...
}
```

Also notice, that C++ has more idiomatic ways of iterating over a container. In particular, C++11 has the range-based `for` loop, which makes it impossible for you to mess with indices or iterators:

```
for (int x : dotsX) { std::cout << x << std::endl; }
```

Comment: But whenever the while loop access a non existing value, it will stop the loop, won't it?

Comment: @anarchy99: No, it won't stop. Accessing an out-of-bounds element is undefined behavior. Also, in your example, the condition which determines whether the loop is entered or not is based on the *value* which is being read (`dotsX[x]`). So if `dotsX[i]` has value `0` for some `i`, that will stop the loop, no matter whether `dotsX` has more than `i` elements

Comment: would just add that the only reason the while loop even terminates is that it runs into a contiguous block of memory beyond the end of the array that just so happens to be set to 0x0000

Comment: It will "stop" by throwing an exception if you would use `dots.at(x)`, since this includes a range check. However you should always make sure the range check is in your code, rather than catching exceptions.

Comment: Okay, thank you for all the help.. I thought that it will stop whenever there are no existing value again.

Answer (score 1):

Your loops don't have the same condition.  The `while` loop version makes at least one access past the end of the vector.  Doing so causes undefined behaviour, and anything could happen.  In your case, it looks like you just get some extra invalid output.

If you change the conditions to match you'll get matching (correct) behaviour:

```
 while (x < dotsX.size())
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectors maintain there size internally one is able to retrieve the size by vector::size() method. Therefore in you for loop you increment x as long as x is smaller than dotX.size(). Your fore loop will abort when it is ready.
You make no check in the while loop whether x is larger than the total cv::Dot's in the vector therefore you get more output in the while version than in the for version in the loop. The while loop will only quit when incidentally dotX is equal to zero, but most likely your program will end prematurely because you access memory that you didn't allocate.

you could try a while loop like this, but the for loop expresses this much better:

```
int x = 0;
while ( true ){
    if ( ! (x < dotsX.size() ) break;
    std::cout << dotsX[x] << std::endl;
    x++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is checking for quantity:

```
x < dotsX.size()
```

Your `while` loop is checking values:

```
dotsX[x]
```

The `while` expression is the same as:

```
while (dotsX[x] != 0)
```

This is probably a typo.